# AWS S3 differing bucket sizes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a bucket in s3, when I click on 'Get size' in https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com it says the total size 5.7TB, in Management>Analytics>Storage class analysis- it says the total size is 17TB, in Management>Metrics>Storage it says the total size is 19TB...

Why is there this difference and which one is right?

Comment: Do you have versioning enabled?

Comment: @stdunbar Yes,versioning is enabled, I can see files listed with 'Delete marker'

Comment: Without knowing more it seems that there are 5.7TB in current files available across all storage classes.  There is 17TB available, both deleted and versioned in at least one storage class.  And there is 19TB total.  But I'm not 100% sure of that - perhaps some screen shots?

Comment: You could turn on [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html) to obtain a detailed listing of objects and sizes.

Comment: you could use the insight for storage tool to scan your bucket and show the breakdown of total storage by current and previous versions and different storage classes https://www.cloudzipinc.com/insight4storage_guide, it was free for a demo.  i'm curious how it compares to the console values